# What reporting suites support EF and DbContext out of the box?

Tags: telerik, reporting

Everywhere I look, I find reporting suites with designers that only understand DataSets (circa 2003?). Even the most promising, Telerik, only supports ObjectContext. I am getting sick of looking to buy a product that costs a lot and is supposed to be up to date and able to handle all modern scenarios.

Does anyone know of such a reporting suite?

Answer (score 2):

Try PdfReport: http://pdfreport.codeplex.com
It supports multiple data sources including strongly typed list from different ORMs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at SharpShooter Reports - http://www.perpetuumsoft.com/Report-Sharp-Shooter.aspx

It has EF support in runtime environment ( http://blogs.perpetuumsoft.com/dotnet/usingentityframework/)
and also has quite extensive support for multiple datasources.